# Get Date Part only from DateTime (SQL Function)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Which of these two functions is more efficient? toDate1 or toDate2 -- Is there something better?

```
use Something
go
-- All SQL versions
create function toDate1(@t datetime)  
    returns datetime as begin  
    declare @return datetime  
    select  @return = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@t),0)
    return  @return end
go
-- SQL 2008 ->
create function toDate2(@t datetime)  
    returns datetime as begin  
    declare @return datetime  
    select  @return = convert(date, @t) 
    return  @return end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think you can really compare those two functions, one is for SQL Server 2008 and above and the other one is for All SQL Server versions.

Comment: Look at the execution plan and see for yourself

Comment: Why do you need a function for this?   [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) will do it for you.

Comment: When you tested it what were your results?

Comment: Neither of them is terribly efficient. They are both scalar functions which are notoriously slow in all versions of sql server.

Comment: An application will read some databases that was created with SQL 5005, but the new comes in SQL 2012 and 2014. therefore I need a common function in both versions. I need the best performance because the queries works over millions of records. I wanted to spare me some time writing something for assessing performance. So the question.

Comment: Sean, shall you say me a better approach?

Comment: for sql-server 2008+ if you just want to return the date from a datetime, you can use cast(mydatetimevar as date)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(date, cast ('2014-01-01 10:11:12' as datetime), 106)
```

it return date `'2014-01-01'` `cast ('2014-01-01 10:11:12' as datetime)` is a datetime variable.
   Please look msdn for more detail